# Got this message saying not to ask for read and write permissions at once

Tags: facebook, permissions

I got this message:
Your app appears to be requesting both read and write permissions at the same time. Instead, request a small number of permissions initially, and ask for write permissions when the user decides to share.

So, I can modify the web application to ask for read permissions when first signing up/signing in. However, there are times when the app will want to publish, but the user has not logged in yet. So, it makes more sense to ask for both permissions at once.

Would this be okay?

Answer (score 0):

Request them one after the other. Just store the post in a temporary location. As you can see it won't let ask you for both at the same time.

That's what most web applications do really, when you click on post or share a window will pop-up asking you to log in if you're not.